# Advice on using standalone package with tabular environment

Tags: tables, environments, standalone

Why is content prescribed by the code contained within the `tabular` environment being truncated (far right) when called using the `standalone` document class as configured in the mwe below?

```
\documentclass[preview,border=7pt,active,tightpage]{standalone}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{filecontents} 
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}

\begin{filecontents}{methane.tex}
\chemfig{
H% 2
    -[:210]% 1
              (
        -[:210]H% 3
              )
              (
        -[:300]H% 5
              )
    -[:120]H% 4
    }
\end{filecontents}

% sans serif font
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault} 

% define formula
\def\methane{\mathrm{CH_{4}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}[]{lp{3.5cm}ccc}
\toprule
\textbf{Formula} & \textbf{Structure} & \textbf{Molar mass} (g mol$^{-1}$) & \textbf{Melting point} ($^{\circ}\mathrm{C}$) & \textbf{Boiling point} ($^{\circ}\mathrm{C}$) \\
\midrule%
$\methane$ & \begin{minipage}[]{1cm} \input{methane.tex} \end{minipage} & 16.043 & -182.50 & -161.50 \\ [2mm]
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

This is likely a case of inadequate configuration of `standalone` on my part.

Comment: Not related to the question but maybe you want to use `siunitx` for the units in the table.

Comment: Regarding the question: Did you already try without the `center` environment?

Comment: @leandriis you nailed it.  Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: (i) remove  `center` environment` and (ii) options `preview` and `tightpage`.

Comment: @leandriis or Zarko would you like to add an answer?

Comment: @Zarko ^^^^^^^^

Comment: @CarLaTeX, of, I'm few seconds to late for writing an answer  :-(

Comment: @Zarko maybe next time :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to remove the truncation, I have removed the `center` environmant as well as some class options in the following example. In order to remove the underfull box warning, I have also changed the width of the minipage from `1cm` to `\linewidth`. With this setting the minipages automatically inherits the width of the `p` tpe column that it is used in.

```
\documentclass[border=7pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{filecontents} 
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}

\begin{filecontents}{methane.tex}
\chemfig{
H% 2
    -[:210]% 1
              (
        -[:210]H% 3
              )
              (
        -[:300]H% 5
              )
    -[:120]H% 4
    }
\end{filecontents}

% sans serif font
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault} 

% define formula
\def\methane{\mathrm{CH_{4}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}[]{lp{3.5cm}ccc}
\toprule
\textbf{Formula} & \textbf{Structure} & \textbf{Molar mass} (g mol$^{-1}$) & \textbf{Melting point} ($^{\circ}\mathrm{C}$) & \textbf{Boiling point} ($^{\circ}\mathrm{C}$) \\
\midrule%
$\methane$ & \begin{minipage}[]{\linewidth} \input{methane.tex} \end{minipage} & 16.043 & -182.50 & -161.50 \\ [2mm]
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

In order to typeset chemical formulae I'd recommen the use of `mhchem` (or `chemformula`) and for the units I'd use `sinuintx`. I have included both in the following example:

```
\documentclass[border=7pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{filecontents} 
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}

\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{filecontents}{methane.tex}
\chemfig{
H% 2
    -[:210]% 1
              (
        -[:210]H% 3
              )
              (
        -[:300]H% 5
              )
    -[:120]H% 4
    }
\end{filecontents}

% sans serif font
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault} 

% define formula
\def\methane{\ce{CH4}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}[]{lp{3.5cm}ccc}
\toprule
\textbf{Formula} & \textbf{Structure} & \textbf{Molar mass} (\si{\gram\per\mole}) & \textbf{Melting point} (\si{\celsius}) & \textbf{Boiling point} (\si{\celsius}) \\
\midrule%
$\methane$ & \begin{minipage}[]{\linewidth} \input{methane.tex} \end{minipage} & 16.043 & -182.50 & -161.50 \\ [2mm]
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use specialized packages, besides not using `preview` and simply typeset the table. Instead of a `minipage` where the width needs to be guessed, use a nested `tabular`.

```latex
\documentclass[margin=4]{standalone}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{chemfig,chemformula,siunitx}
\usepackage{filecontents} 
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}

\begin{filecontents}{methane.tex}
\chemfig{
H% 2
    -[:210]% 1
              (
        -[:210]H% 3
              )
              (
        -[:300]H% 5
              )
    -[:120]H% 4
    }
\end{filecontents}

% sans serif font
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{
  l
  c
  S[table-format=2.3]
  S[table-format=-3.2]
  S[table-format=-3.2]
}
\toprule
\textbf{Formula} &
\textbf{Structure} &
{\textbf{Molar mass} (\si{\gram\per\mol})} &
{\textbf{Melting point} (\si{\celsius})} &
{\textbf{Boiling point} (\si{\celsius})} \\
\midrule
\ch{CH4} & \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}\input{methane.tex}\end{tabular} & 16.043 & -182.50 & -161.50 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Slightly modified @leandriis [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/502693/advice-on-using-standalone-package-with-tabular-environment/505319#505319):

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=7pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}

\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\makegapedcells

\usepackage{chemfig}
\newcommand\methane{\chemfig{H -[:0]C (-[:90]H)(-[:270]H)(-[:0]H)}}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{siunitx}


\begin{document}
\setchemfig{atom sep=2em}
\begin{tabular}[]{l c SSS}
    \toprule
\thead{Formula}
            & \thead{Structure}
                & {\thead{Molar mass\\ (\si{\gram\per\mole})}}
                            & {\thead{Melting point\\ (\si{\celsius})}}
                                        & {\thead{Boiling point\\ (\si{\celsius})}}  \\
    \midrule
\ce{CH4}    & \methane 
                & 16.043    & -182.50   & -161.50 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

As I noted in my comment below question the cause of your problem is used `center` anvironment`. Also options options`preview `and`tightpage`are superfluous. The package`siunitx`is also exploited for numbers in your table, and`makecell` for more compact column headers.